# OpenOffice - COUNTIF подставить в регулярное выражение имя ячейки

Tags: open-office

Есть формула которая ищет в диапазоне ячеек некого столбца значения `id` с номером `1`

```
= COUNTIF(B1:B200; "(.*)id=1")
```

Как мне подставить вместо `1` значение из ячейки к примеру `A1`?

Делал так:

```
= COUNTIF(B1:B200; "(.*)id=$A1")
```

Возвращает ноль, так как я понимаю в регулярке не работают переменные? То как быть тогда?

Comment: А так? `= COUNTIF(B1:B200; "(.*)id="&$A1)`

Comment: Почти, так работает, ваш вариант не проверял *"&A13&"* (перед открытой и закрытой скобкой идет символ астериска)